# Looking for a resource about the poor system in early 19th century Denmark

Tags: terminology, german-language, denmark

Is there a good resource for learning terminology used in the 1840 Denmark poor system, and how that system functioned? I have already read the FHL wiki about poor in Denmark.

I am looking in then-Danish, German-speaking areas. I see notations in census and church records from the market towns of Ringkøbing and Sønderborg.

I cannot read what comes after Diedrich Hanssen, 64, married, carpenter. I think it has to do with pension or poor money. (If you're feeling generous, what is 4. Lorenz Hanssen's occupation? Five years later he is a sailor.)
[1835 Denmark census Diedrich Hanssen](https://www.sa.dk/ao-soegesider/en/billedviser?bsid=187537#187537,31779442)

[image: Ohlsen 1835 census]

The second image is from the 1840 census and, again, I think she is receiving poor money because her husband died. In the 1845 census, Brigitta's entry notes Armengeld.
[1840 Denmark census Brigitte H Ohlsen](https://www.sa.dk/ao-soegesider/en/billedviser?bsid=188073#188073,31867424)

The original images are very poor; this is the clearest possible. Neither of these census records appear in the DDD, which is a terrific resource.

[image: Brigitte Ohlsen 1840 census, no. 99]

The third image is from an 1838 confirmation. His 1846 marriage states both his parents died and he was raised at the expense of the poor fund in Ringkøbing market town. The marriage record mentions this same resolution, but the confirmation is the most legible.
[Rasmus Jacobsen confirmation, no. 5](https://www.sa.dk/ao-soegesider/en/billedviser?bsid=399165#399165,74475433)
[Rasmus Jacobsen marriage, no. 7](https://www.sa.dk/ao-soegesider/en/billedviser?epid=17217330#202602,38406999)

[image: Rasmus conf 1838]

Comment: Since you tagged your question as "german-language", are you interested specifically in the poor system in Denmark proper, or in the then-Danish, German-speaking parts (such as SchleswigI?

Comment: I found some sources, but I'm not sure whether these qualify as an answer yet: [overview of poor laws](https://danmarkshistorien.dk/leksikon-og-kilder/vis/materiale/fattiglovgivningen-i-danmark-1660-1849-fra-tiggertegn-til-grundlovssikret-ret/), and [the poor law of 1803](https://danmarkshistorien.dk/leksikon-og-kilder/vis/materiale/fattigreglement-for-danmarks-koebstaeder-1803/). They are in Danish language.

Comment: [poor laws in Eiderstedt](https://www.heimatbund-eiderstedt.de/historisches-eiderstedt/gesellschaftliches/index.html) and [poor laws in Eiderstedt, in particular in St. Peter Ording](https://www.chronik-spo.de/eiderstedt-1/a/armenwesen/) are German language resources on poor laws in a part of Schleswig.

Comment: If you have questions about specific terms in the records, then it might be helpful to discuss them directly.

Comment: The census images are publicly available, could you provide the place/city and page where these are from?

Comment: The occupation of Lorenz Hansen could very well be "Matrose" (so, sailor would fit).

Comment: The remark for the widow in 1845 says "erhält Unterstützung" ("receives support", the end of the last word is a bit cryptic/abbreviated, I think). The one for the family in 1840 says "Erhält wöchentliche Unterstützung" ("receives weekly support", as far as I can tell).

Comment: I added links to the specific documents in the Danish Archives @jadepx. Rasmus Jacobsen's confirmation and marriage records have the information about being raised at the expense of the poor fund. (I found another record with "Matrose", so am grateful for your kind assistance.)